# indicate row in a data frame in lapply function

Tags: r

I have a longitudinal dataframe:

```
 id= rep(1:3,each= 3)
 a_yr = rep(1994:1996,3)
 b_yr = c(1994,1995,1997,1994,1998,2001,1994,1997, 1998)
 x= 1:9
 df= data.frame(id,a_yr,b_yr,x)

  ids a_yr b_yr x
1   1 1994 1994 1
2   1 1995 1995 2
3   1 1996 1997 3
4   2 1994 1994 4
5   2 1995 1998 5
6   2 1996 2001 6
7   3 1994 1994 7
8   3 1995 1997 8
9   3 1996 1998 9
```

I want to create a subset that contains the rows that **the 1st** `a_yr` matches `b_yr`  for each id:

```
   ids a_yr b_yr x

2   1 1994 1994 1
4   2 1994 1994 4
7   3 1994 1994 7
```

I tried to use `lapply` function :

```
lapply(unique(df$id), function(i){
  data= df[which(df$id==i),]
  rownames(data)<- data$a_yr
  ind = data[1,"b_yr"]
  dat= data[ind,]
})
```

But it returned a bunch of `NA`s.

```
[[1]]
   id a_yr b_yr  x
NA NA   NA   NA NA

[[2]]
   id a_yr b_yr  x
NA NA   NA   NA NA

[[3]]
   id a_yr b_yr  x
NA NA   NA   NA NA
```

I wonder how to index rows in `lapply` function or any other better ways to solve this problem.
Thank you very much!

Comment: This should give you what you want: `df[df$a_yr==df$b_yr,]`

Comment: Your example and expected output is not matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in base R:

```
df[df$a_yr==df$b_yr,]

  id a_yr b_yr x
2  1 1995 1995 2
4  2 1994 1994 4
7  3 1994 1994 7
```

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of ways, here is one:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(a_yr==b_yr)




   #     id  a_yr  b_yr     x
   #   (int) (int) (dbl) (int)
   #1     1  1995  1995     2
   #2     2  1994  1994     4
   #3     3  1994  1994     7
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[a_yr==b_yr]
```